# curl.perform throws invalid easy handle error under multi-threading env

Tags: ruby, curl, curb

I use curl of ruby gem curb to fetch multi urls under multi-threading env, but it throws "Invalid easy handle" exception, but if it runs one by one in single-threading env everything is ok.

```
module Http
  @@curl = Curl::Easy.new
  @@curl.timeout = 10 #second
  @@curl.follow_location = true
  @@curl.max_redirects = 3
  @@options = Robot::HttpOptions.new

  def self.fetch(url, options=@@options, type=Robot::Type::HTML)
    @@curl.url = URI.unescape(url)==url ? URI.escape(url) : url
    @@curl.headers["User-Agent"] = options.user_agent
    begin
      @@curl.perform
    rescue Curl::Err::CurlError
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

self.fetch is called in multi-threading env.

Can someone help me on the thing? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [cURL documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html):

> You must never share the same handle in multiple threads.

Comment: thank you. But if i don't share the curl handle it will consume more cost, is there some way between correctness and performance in multi-threading?

Comment: No, you need to have one curl handle per thread. Limit your number of threads to a reasonable amount if you're worried about the memory cost. The performance cost is **less** if each thread has its own handle - no (or very minimal) locking involved. (i.e. it is probably faster this way.)